# Can my cleric/warlock's deity and patron have opposing alignments?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, cleric

In the campaign, I'm participating in, my character is a wizard/warlock with Vecna as his Patron, his ultimate goal being to achieve lichdom. In order to obtain more knowledge about magic in general to continue his research, I'm considering taking a dip in arcana cleric of Mystra to get some divine help and those cleric spells. The problem is that Vecna is NE and Mystra is NG, so I really don't know how they would get along. I know that they are from different worlds, but I don't know if their differences in opinions would make it difficult for my character. Would there be any chance that my character could successfully pull off having both Mystra and Vecna in his head without any controversy between the two?

Comment: As is this question is a bit of a run on paragraph that jumps around a lot and doesn't clearly define exactly what you are trying to ask, can you try to edit it so that what you are asking is more clear?

Comment: This sounds like you just need to discuss the concept with your group.

Comment: It appears that OP is asking whether it's possible to be cleric of a NG deity while also a warlock of an NE patron, or if the two would clash in an incompatbile manner.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard yes

Comment: Does [Warlock/Cleric: Would the Fiend and a God Get Along?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67982/) come close enough to your situation to answer your question?  Your situation is slightly different, but I suspect the answers there are applicable.